# very strange behaviour of settimeout function and object declaration?

Tags: javascript, this, settimeout

```
var user = {

firstName: 'Вася',
sayHi: function(who) {
    console.log(`firstname - ${this.firstName}: Привет, ${who}`);
    }
}


setTimeout( function() {user.sayHi('asd')}, 2000  );
```

i get **user.sayHi** is not a function error cuz **user** is not defined in context of setTimeout call. afaik setTimeout context is window, and defining object via **var** will put that object into **window object**, then why it is undefined(**1**) ?

**2**. changing var to let will work ! why?

**3**. typing

`var x = user`

and changing **user.sayHi** to **x.sayHi** will work aswell !! I dont understand why. Since var x and var user are same definitions to me.
Pls explain

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://jsbin.com/doxegukana/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Do you have any more code beyond this that might happen to also be using the `user` variable? It seems that something else must be changing it so that it's no longer pointing to the object defined in this snippet.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using snippet ?

Comment: whoops. ty James, indeed another script interfere, sorry for taking ur time :) *shy*

Comment: I'm guessing you are using a for loop on users (multiple). Suggest you use users.forEach instead. Something like `users.forEach(user=>setTimeout(()=>user.sayHi('asd')))`

Comment: the given snippet of code is working fine. I don't find any issue. Is anything you are missing .

Comment: if you're using a for loop and have to wait for async or delayed stuff, I'd suggest you to use Promises

Answer (score -1):

I'm just guessing here but think you are using timeout in a loop over users, something like:

```js
var users = [1, 2];
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() =>
    console.log(
      'why 2?',
      i,
      'users[2] is undefined',
      users[i],
    ),
  );
}
```

If you use `let` then the variable i is block scoped, each loop gets it's own i:

```js
var users = [1, 2];
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() =>
    console.log(
      'let works:',
      i,
      users[i],
    ),
  );
}
```

As stated before; the let works because each itteration gets its own i variable but with var there is only window.i and by the time the setTimeout function executes window.i has a value of 2. Demonstrated next with an extra console.log

```js
var users = [1, 2];
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() =>
    console.log(
      'now you know why 2!',
      i,
      'users[2] is undefined',
      users[i],
    ),
  );
}
console.log('after the loop before the timeout, and i is:',i);
```

Your var code probably works because you're creating a user variable that will contain the last user:

```js
var users = [1, 2];
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var user = users[i]
  setTimeout(() =>
    console.log(
      'i still is 2',
      i,
      'user is 2 both times as there is only one window.user',
      user,
    ),
  );
}
console.log('after the loop, user is:',user);
```

So as a solution you could use let but I prefer using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var users = [1, 2];
users.forEach((user) =>
  setTimeout(() =>
    console.log(
      'no more temporary i counter variable, user is:',
      user,
    ),
  ),
);
console.log('after foreach');
```

If I'm completely wrong then sorry for that, had to guess since you're describing a common loop problem but posted code that does not cause any of the behavior you describe.